# sum() by group sql

Tags: php, sql

I have data in a row with same `value` and `id` example below:

table_name: test

```
id | amount
 1 |   100
 1 |   100
 1 |   100 
 2 |   150
 2 |   150
 2 |   150
 3 |   200
 3 |   200
 3 |   200
 4 |   250
 4 |   250
 4 |   250
```

I want to sum only one row in each `id`using `sql` below is not working it sum all the row.

```
"select *, sum(amount) as total from test group by id";
```

my question is that possible to `sum()` only one `row` each `id`?

**desired output?**(***edit***)

```
id | amount
 1 |   100
 2 |   150
 3 |   200
 4 |   250

total : 700
```

Comment: what is the desired output?

Comment: @DarkKnight update my question above.

Comment: do you want total as output or the above table as output? or both?

Comment: thank your for your time to share your answer, but I prepared  @Gordon Linoff answer. but thank you anyway co'z this problem make my head out of nowhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my question is that possible to sum() only one row each id?

I interpret this as your wanting one value, with a single row from each group.  One method is two levels of aggregation:

```
select sum(amount)
from (select id, max(amount) as amount
      from test
      group by id
     ) t;
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need this

```
select *,sum(amount) from (select distinct * from test) as t group by id
```

Comment: it return same result with my query above.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select id, sum(amount)/count(*) as total 
from test 
group by id
```

Result:

```
| id | total |
|----|-------|
|  1 |   100 |
|  2 |   150 |
|  3 |   200 |
|  4 |   250 |
```

Answer (score 1):

try this using subquery-

```
select sum(amount) from (select distinct id,amount from company7) as tempTable
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
create table #test
(id int, amount int)

insert into #test values (1,100),(1,100),(1,100),(2,150),(2,150),(3,200),(3,250)

;with cte
as
(
select sum(distinct amount) as damount,id
from #test
group by id
)

select sum(damount) as total from cte
```

For other DBMSs  than SQL Server

```
select sum(damount) as total from (select sum(distinct amount) as damount,id
from test
group by id) as it
```